# Wordpress 5.5 - ReferenceError: commonL10n is not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, admin, errors

I just upgraded to the latest version of wordpress 5.5 and my theme stopped working.
The categories are no longer automatically selected when I click the button.

https://prnt.sc/u030gj

Comment: Does WordPress work with a default theme enabled (Twenty Twenty, for example)? If so, you'll need to consult your theme's official support streams.

Comment: Try to purge your browser cache.

Comment: Purging cache helped me, weird issue, never seen this before.

Comment: See ticket: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51123

Comment: On 15/10/2020 downgrade to 5.4.2
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-downgrade/

Answer (score 1):

This is [Trac ticket 51223](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51123):

> commonL10n and other JS globals removed without backwards compatibility
>
> In WordPress 5.5, the localized translations under commonL10n were replaced by wp.i18n.__ without deprecation notice or backwards compatibility. Plugins using commonL10n now have JavaScript errors introduced by updating WordPress which can break site functionality.

It was [fixed in 5.5.1](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/48925) by adding a compatibility layer. The best fix is to upgrade to 5.5.1.

commonL10n is still deprecated, however, and [will be removed in 5.7](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51317).